# Why does the button print twice? (Kivy Python)

Tags: python, button, kivy

I'm trying to make a button and I'm doing this print as a test, I'm not why it prints twice?
I'm new to Kivy so I'm not too sure on what I'm doing, any help is appreciated thank you.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


def bannedBooksMain(self, instance):
    print('The button test is being pressed')

class mainApp(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(mainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        btn1 = Button(text='Home Page')
        btn1.bind(state=bannedBooksMain)
        self.add_widget(btn1)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return mainApp()
MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The state changes when you press and when you release. Use `on_press=` instead of `state=`

Answer (score 0):

```
btn1.bind(state=bannedBooksMain)
```

This (`state=`) will initiate a callback whenever the state property changes, this happens for both button press *and* release, which is why you're seeing it twice

You should use `on_press=` or `on_release=` instead, depending on when you want the action fired.

Personally, I prefer the `on_release=` combined with `always_release` being false. That way, if I inadvertently press the button, I can move the mouse point away from the button before releasing, and there will be no callback.

See [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html) for further detail.